Remove leftmost point from convex hull
I have a set of N 2d points sorted by x coordinate and upper convex hull for this set. I'm trying to update current convex hull after I've deleted the leftmost point from set or inserted new point to the right.
Insertion can be done in O(logN) using binary search.
There is a problem with deletion. Lets have an example of the worst case. Suppose we have a set of black points and we remove red point. After that the convex hull should be totally updated. This leads to O(N) time complexity.

Is there any algorithm to support deletion from left in no more than O(logN)?

This belongs to a class of problems called 'dynamic convex hull problems' -- maintaining a convex hull under discrete changes like inserting, deleting, or modifying nodes.
As your example demonstrates, it's possible for the deleting of a single vertex to alter a convex hull from a triangle to one that includes all remaining points. In this case, the output is linear. The complexity can't be better than the output, so the complexity is at best O(n).

In this case I agree with you. What about additional data structures for maintaining some data which can help us to reduce complexity?
